# How can I query a mysql database using jquery and ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I have a form with a "select" box. When the box is selected, I want the appropriate records from the database to be shown on the same page.

There are two files involved: an HTML page that contains the form:

```
<form id="theForm">
<select id="theDropdown">
<option value="biology">Biology</option>
<option value="chemistry">Chemistry</option>
<option value="english">English</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="resultsGoHere"></div>
```

and also contains the jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#theDropdown').on('change', function() {
       var qString = '{sub: ' + $('#theDropdown option:selected').text() + '}';
       $.post('sub_db_handler.php', qString, processResponse);
       // $('#resultsGoHere').html(qString);
    });

    function processResponse(data) {
        $('#resultsGoHere').html(data);
    }

});
</script>
```

The jQuery code seems to successfully grab the selected value of the select menu and formats a JSON query string, which is printed out if the commented line above is uncommented.

Here is the PHP script that is referred to in the `post` command above.

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","rongilmo_ron","******");
if(!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("rongilmo_databases", $con);
$sub = $_POST['theDropdown'];

$q = "SELECT dbs.db_name, dbs.db_url FROM dbs, subjects, subjects_databases
WHERE subjects.subject_id=subjects_databases.subject_id
AND subjects_databases.database_id=dbs.db_id
AND subjects.subject_name='$sub'";

$r = mysql_query($q);
$array = mysql_fetch_row($r);
echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

I get no results at all. I've tested the query in non-ajax mode, so that isn't the problem.

Still new to ajax.  I've been working on this for two days and can't seem to make it work, despite reading lots of tutorials and doing a lot of googling.

Any help you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PHP uses the html name attribute not the id attribute.

Comment: You've tested the query but have you tested the PHP code by viewing it in a browser without any ajax calls? The server side code should be fully tested before you move on to try and consume it via ajax.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

Give your select a name attribute.

```
<form id="theForm">
    <select id="theDropdown" name="theDropdown">
        <option value="biology">Biology</option>
        <option value="chemistry">Chemistry</option>
        <option value="english">English</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="resultsGoHere"></div>
```

**Update.**
PHP is expecting a query string in the standard URL-encoded notation not JSON.  By sending it the following way the $_POST array should contain 'sub' with the value of the selected option.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#theDropdown').change(function() {   
        var qString = 'sub=' +$(this).val();
        $.post('sub_db_handler.php', qString, processResponse);
    });

    function processResponse(data) {
        $('#resultsGoHere').html(data);
    }

});
</script>

<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","rongilmo_ron","******");
    if(!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
    mysql_select_db("rongilmo_databases", $con);
    $sub = $_POST['sub'];

    $q = "SELECT dbs.db_name, dbs.db_url FROM dbs, subjects, subjects_databases
    WHERE subjects.subject_id=subjects_databases.subject_id
    AND subjects_databases.database_id=dbs.db_id
    AND subjects.subject_name='$sub'";

    $r = mysql_query($q);
    $array = mysql_fetch_row($r);
    echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Comment: an often forgotten attribute.  Just ran into that the other day.  Serialize doesn't work either without the name attr out there...

Comment: Adding the name attribute isn't having any effect.

Comment: Comment out your echo and do a print_r($_POST).  What is returned?

Comment: using `serialize()` now rather than trying to construct my own JSON string. Getting better results.

Comment: Many thanks, Jrod. Your non-JSON, "sub=" method works beautifully and makes more sense than using `serialize()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ajax $.getJson() to return a json string. It will require you to use $each on the json string. See the jquery document on the website http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/